# Evaluating the limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{\sin{x^2}}e^{(t^2)}dt}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, integration

I am to find the $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{\sin{x^2}}e^{(t^2)}dt}{x^2}$$ and I have no idea how to approach this. As its widely known, there's no way to integrate $e^{(x^2)}$, how should I do it? All kind of tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You could use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess, given the form of the integral and of the limit, that the party who posed the problem to **darenn** was up to something a bit snarky.

We can define the integral function $$ \ F(x^2) \ = \ \int_{0}^{\sin{x^2}}e^{(t^2)}dt \ \ . $$

The limit  $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\int_{0}^{\sin{x^2}}e^{(t^2)} \ dt}{x^2} \ $ can then be written as

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \  \frac{( \int_{0}^{\sin{x^2}}e^{(t^2)} \ dt ) \ - \ ( \int_{0}^{\sin{0^2}}e^{(t^2)} \ dt ) }{x^2} \  , $$

which now resembles the limit definition of a point derivative.  Hence, we have

$$ \lim_{x^2 \rightarrow 0} \  \frac{F(0 + x^2) \ - \ F(0)  }{x^2} \ = \ F'(0) \ = \ e^{[\sin(0^2)]^2} \ \cdot  \ \cos(0^2) \ = \ e^0  \cdot \cos(0) \ = \ 1 \ , $$

by applying "Liebniz' Rule". $ ^{*} $

$ ^{*} $ at least, this is what I've sometimes seen the formula for differentiating an integral function, with an integration limit being a function, called... There is something else that seems to be more usually called "Liebniz' Rule".

**EDIT:** Oops, did that a bit too quick and neglected the Chain Rule; fortunately, that other factor is *also* 1 . (There is also a bit of abuse here, since I am differentiating with respect to $ \ x^2 \ $ , so the Chain Rule does not produce yet another factor after $ \ \cos(x^2) \ $ ... )

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of doing it this way! Thats superb, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Like I say, I don't think it's intended to be immediately obvious.  It was just that the integral looks so much like the sort that are in problems posed where you are supposed to differentiate by applying "Liebniz"...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Perhaps you mean **Leibniz**?

Comment: @Lord_Farin  Gah, yes!  Sorry, I've neglected the "never say 'die' " rule for German; worse, I did that three times.  Clearly, more coffee is called for...

Comment: Haha, nice answer, +1.

Answer (score 3):

The function $t\mapsto e^{t^2}$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, hence for all $x$
$$\frac{\sin x^2\cdot 1}{x^2}<\frac1{x^2}\int_0^{\sin x^2}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt<\frac{\sin x^2\cdot e^{\sin^2(x^2)}}{x^2} $$
Noting that $\frac {\sin t}t\to 1$ as $t\to 0$, and by contuínuity $e^{\sin^2x^2}\to 1$, we see that the limit in question is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using L'Hopital's Rule and The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus